# Ruby Procs - ends up with syntax error

Tags: ruby, proc

Trying to understand Procs on Ruby, and for this I am trying some exercices.

First I type this line

```
[1, 4, 5, 3].map(&:anything)
```

And as a result I got an error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `anything' for 1:Fixnum`.

Then I try this one:

```
[1, 4, 5, 3].map(&:to_s)
```

And a new array with the numbers transformed to string was returned:

> => ["1", "4", "5", "3"]`.

With those two examples, I can conclude that, when I call something like: `[1, 4, 5, 3].map(&:anything)` the `anything` method is called for each element in the array. And because a Fixnum don't implement the `anything` method, the first example ends with error and the second passed.

Then I think, if Fixnum have a `+` method, then I can call `[1, 4, 5, 3].map(&:+2)`. But this ends with a syntax error:

> syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ')' [1, 4, 5, 3].map(&:+2)

why this last is giving me this syntax error if a Fixum have a `+` method ? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is a shortcut for calling the `to_proc` method.
Because you have a symbol (`:anything`) the `to_proc` method is called on the symbol. This returns a proc which will call the method with the corresponding name (`anything`) on the object that is passed as argument.

If you do this with an enumerator like `map` then you actually call the method on each object in the collection.

Now this shortcut does not allow you to pass an argument to the methods. (`+` is just syntactic sugar for calling a method on a number that takes another method as argument)

But you can use currying for such a use case:

```
add = -> (a, b) { a + b }
add_two = add.curry.call(2)

p [1,2,3,4].map(&add_two) # => [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `&:method_name` is a shortcut that can be used instead of `{|x| x.anything}` - and only exactly that. It can be used by any method that receives a block.

```
# So this line...
[1,2,3].map(&:anything)

# ... is equivalent to this line
[1,2,3].map {|x| x.anything }

# Same can go here:
[job1, job2, job2].each(&:process)
```

Note that you can only use it for methods that receive no arguments. Since you were trying to send the argument `2`, you received a syntax error.